# Brew Invalid Archive Format

Tags: macos, rust, homebrew

Im trying to install the zld linker for use with Rust using `brew install zld`, however I keep getting the same error:

```
tar: Error opening archive: Unrecognized archive format
make: *** [tapi-1100.0.11] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I have tried updating homebrew, used `brew cleanup --prune=all` between all attempts, tried installing it from a uncompressed and compressed directory using `brew install -f`, and none of them work, it all ends up throwing the same error. What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in upstream. There's a PR in to fix it [here](https://github.com/michaeleisel/zld/pull/121/files). In the mean time you could install it from [the releases](https://github.com/michaeleisel/zld/releases) or build it [from source](https://github.com/michaeleisel/zld#building-from-source).